# Nested virtual classes in Java

Tags: java, polymorphism, inner-classes

If we consider the following code, polymorphism should happen as it is allowed in nested classes in java but, when invoking the `inner class` constructor `polymorphism` does not apply that is the `new Innner1()` apply to the declared type of the instance
not on the actual type.

```
public class Outer {

    public class In {
        public In() {
            System.out.println("I am In");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Outer obj = new Outer2();
        obj.new In();
        Outer2 in2 = (Outer2) obj;
        in2.new In();
    }

}

class Outer2 extends Outer {
    public class In extends Outer.In {
        public In() {
            System.out.println("I am In2");
        }
    }
}
```

Can some help me understand this behavior.

**Guys i have updated the Code and it is compiling fine and there is no class cast exception**

Please check the output  below.

```
I am In
I am In
I am In2
```

Comment: uh... you can´t just cast `Outer` to `Outer2`... `obj` is an instance of `Outer` but not an instance of `Outer2`

Comment: Code is compiling fine and out is there ...

Comment: The compiler wont tell you that `(Outer2) obj` is actually not really working and wont check for it. It will just cause a `ClassCastException` at `Runtime` as it´s your job to do valid and checked casting of types (using `instanceof` for example).

Comment: what output would you expect? As the code is now correct in terms of typecasting i´d say everything works as expected, at least for me.

Comment: THere is no polymorphisim, as i mentioned in my question ..

Comment: you create an `Outer`, no constructor thoughs no output. You create an `Outer.In`, thoughs `In` constructor prints. You create an `Outer2`, no constructor again thougs no output. You create an `Outer2.In` and as though you get both `Outer.In` and `Outer2.In` constructor output. So still, what´s the expected output and the question? That´s `4` steps in the main creating the 3 expectable outputs. if you mean `obj.new In()`, `obj` is declared as `Outer`, even if it´s actually an `Outer2`, this will create an `Outer.In`, as you acces types, methods and others things through the declared type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What´s happening here and why is this special output produced:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    Outer obj = new Outer2();  // Step 1
    obj.new In();              // Step 2
    Outer2 in2 = (Outer2) obj; // Step 3
    in2.new In();              // Step 4
 }
```

Step 1:

You create an instance of `Outer2` and assign it to a variable `obj` declared as `Outer`. This will execute the `Outer2` and `Outer` default constructors.

Step 2:

You create an `In`. The behaviour what would really be created would be better to understand when both inner classes wouldn´t be called `In`, but as `obj` is declared as `Outer` the call `obj.new In()`, due to the type of `obj`, will create an `Outer > In`.

Here you get your first output :

```
I am In
```

Step 3:

You once again create an instance of `Outer2` and assign it to a variable `in2` declared as `Outer2`!! <-- this is really important here.

This will execute the `Outer2` and `Outer` default constructors.

Step 4:

You create an `In` again. But now, as `in2` is declared as `Outer2`, the call `in2.new In()`, due to the type of `in2`, will create an `Outer2 > In`now.

Here you get your second and third output now:

```
I am In
I am In2
```

Answer (score -1):

As per your code you are trying to create an object of child class in parent.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Outer obj = new Outer();

        obj.new Innner1();

        Outer2 obj2 = (Outer2) obj;
        obj2.new Innner1();
    }
```

Ideally this is not a valid case, because first the parent class should be created then child, else this it becomes a never ending hierarchy. That the parent will have child object, which again will have a parent relation and thereon. This is the reason when you execute your current code you get a response like

Exception in thread "main" `java.lang.ClassCastException: Outer cannot be cast to Outer2`
    at Outer.main(Outer.java:14)
I am In

Ideally you should have

```
 public class Outer {

    public class Innner1 {
        public Innner1() {
            System.out.println("I am In");
        }
    }
}
```

and outer2 as

```
class Outer2 extends Outer {
    public class Innner1 extends Outer.Innner1 {
        public Innner1() {
            System.out.println("I am In2");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Outer obj = new Outer();

        obj.new Innner1();

        Outer2 obj2 = new Outer2();
        obj2.new Innner1();
    }
}
```

In this case the result would be

```
I am In
I am In
I am In2
```

You see here the constructor of parent's Inner class in invoked before the child class'.